# bash hotkey or special operator to save contents of bash prompt input to file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

when i need to accomplish something on the command-line i often start with the default $> prompt. i do this so that i can get fast feedback while iterating a complex command.  more often than not, though, the command gets large and unweildy for the command line. also, if i proved the command sequence i've enterred has been validated (it works) i like to save that input sequence to a file so that i can extend and abstract parts of it for later re-use. how do i grab the contents of that particular history entry?

perhaps i could use `history -a` to output all history to an external file and `grep` that then pipe it to an output file.

what would be ideal would be a special operator like `!<#>` which actually executes the command, except in this case, rather than executing, it just returns the actual command sequence as text for me to output to a file.

what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

`echo !<#>` where `<#>` is the line number of the command in your bash history.

if you type `history <#>` where `<#>` is an integer defining the limit of the lines of output, you get the bash history.

run through `grep` with `history 100 | grep "command command-options"` where command and command-options are what you are looking for. Now you can see your list of your commands that match your grep search criteria.

If the line number in your history is, say, 502, you can simply type `echo !502` and get that entry. this can then be piped into an output file.

```
echo !502 > myscriptfile
```